# How cancel jQuery mouseleave action

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseleave

I want my div to slide up back to the start position when my mouse goes out, but I want my div to cancel that action and go back to its expanded position if the mouse goes back over the div again.

I need some way to stop this action:

```
    $(".logo").mouseleave(function(){
            $(".logo").animate({top: '-65px'}, 'slow')
    });
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gaPah/6/

Comment: Can you clarify: User clicks Toggle, mouse leaves .logo, mouse enters .logo without clicking toggle and that's where you want it to expand again.

Comment: Still need some clarification here. Can you list the chain of events starting from "page loads. Div is collapsed. User hovers over div"

Comment: The user clicks the TOGGLE, the div expands, the cursor leaves the div waits a few milliseconds, and returns to the small size, but during that wait, or during the animation of slideup, the cursor back, div returns to the expanded state.
I apologize for the poor clarity of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally got to the bottom of this. User clicks toggled. Div opens. User leaves div. It waits 700ms then closes. If the user interrupts it closing it reopens. If the user doesn't interrupt, it resets.

NB. `.delay()` does not play well with `.animate()` so it gets complicated, but I'm sure there would be an easier way to do this.

Also note, I've bound custom event `openme` to avoid writing the same animate line twice (once on mouseover and once on click of the button).

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gaPah/14/)

```
$('#btn_panel').click(function(event){
  $(".logo").trigger('openme');
});

$('.logo').on('openme', function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({top: 0}, 700);
}).on('mouseenter', function(){
  clearTimeout($(this).to);
  if (parseInt($(this).css('top'))>-65){
      $(this).trigger('openme');
  }
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
  var el=$(this);
  $(this).to=setTimeout(function(){
    el.animate({top: -65}, 700);
  },700);
});
```

Comment: This is almost what I want, but I just want the panel to expand when I click the TOGGLE.
And I wanted to get some lag before it do slideup automatic, about 700ms
Thank you so much

Comment: So you don't want it to collapse at all?

Comment: The user clicks the TOGGLE, the div expands, the cursor leaves the div waits a few milliseconds, and returns to the small size, but during that wait, or during the animation of slideup, the cursor back, div returns to the expanded state.
I apologize for the poor clarity of the question.

Comment: So if the user leaves it to collapse fully it  doesn't re-open until they click toggle again?

Comment: exactly! just expand when clicks, not onmouseover

Comment: this doesn't work. $(this).to is undefined in mouseenter and el is not defined in scope of setTimeout function.

Comment: @FlashThunder really? i've outputted both to the console http://jsfiddle.net/gaPah/17/

Answer (score 2):

[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is the answer to your problem!

Because you want to stop the animation where it is instead of finishing it fast, you want to use

```
.stop(true, false)
```

on your element.

Here is a Demo of stop() applied to your case: http://jsfiddle.net/Ma5Xt/1/

This is the example with delay added: http://jsfiddle.net/Ma5Xt/2/

Finally, this one will allow expanding on mouseenter only when the closing animation is currently running. Otherwise, you need to click the div to reopen again: http://jsfiddle.net/Ma5Xt/3/

Comment: they're not asking "animate is waiting for the previous animation to finish"

Comment: Quote from the question: "I want my div to cancel that action"

Comment: "if the mouse goes back over the div again" .stop() is not ALL  they need. They want the script to remember Toggled was clicked and, if so, expand on hover.

Comment: As you said in your comment: clarify! Because "I need some way to stop this action:" is exactly the question I answered...

Comment: You've taken their use of "stop" a little literally!

Comment: What i want, is toggle on mouse out, with some delay, but interrupt and back to expanded position, if the mouse gets back over to the div again

Comment: In respond to "exactly! just expand when clicks, not onmouseover" I've done another edit to the example code: http://jsfiddle.net/Ma5Xt/3/

Comment: now i have this [jsfiddle.net/gaPah/15/](http://jsfiddle.net/gaPah/15/) but the delay its not really working :s maybe use settimeout?

Comment: Hm. I wasn't able to produce a non-working delay... http://jsfiddle.net/gaPah/16/

Comment: thanks, its that :D
both [http://jsfiddle.net/gaPah/14/](http://jsfiddle.net/gaPah/14/) and  [http://jsfiddle.net/gaPah/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/gaPah/16/) are working fine. I apologize all the confusions and some mistakes, I have no great fluency in the English language